# After created a file it got extra './ ' on path

Tags: java, linux, file, path

I created an empty `File` and store the extracted value/content from a jar. The jar is running on linux.

```
String filename ="base_script";
File targetFile = new File( filename + ".sh");
String pathStr=null;

//empty file 
targetFile.createNewFile();

if(targetFile.exists()) {
        InputStream link = (getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.userScriptPath));
        Files.copy(link,
                   targetFile.getAbsoluteFile().toPath(),
                   java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        pathStr = targetFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

This is the file path `./base_script.sh`

And this is file absolute path `apps/MyApps/./base_script.sh`

My question is why there's an extra  `./` on the absolute path?

Comment: relative path first resolved to cwd ./ ; the absolute path prefixes to relative and so includes ./

Comment: I got ``no such file or directory``error  when I run it. It works if there's no ``./``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you have "./" in the name as you define the value without it. Anyway this will resolve the path to the real name without any "./" or ".." in a path:

```
pathStr = targetFile.toPath().toRealPath().toString()
```